# classic ASP recordset field not being allowed to evaluate

Tags: asp-classic

I am returning a value from my database. The data type is a string. I checked with TypeName. However, my if condition never works despite it printing the value I am checking for. Any ideas?

```
while NOT prs.EOF

    RecordStatus = prs("status")


    If (RecordStatus = "S") Then
        response.write("Scheduled!<br>")
        prs.MoveNext
    Else
        response.write(RecordStatus & "<BR>")
        prs.MoveNext
   End If

Wend
prs.Close
```

Comment: Try Trim(RecordStatus) = "S"

Comment: No problem. Since you're already receiving the value, I thought possibly it might be the cause. By the way, I think you're new to SO, I will post this as answer and please mark it so that it gets removed from unanswered queue, saving time for others.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Also, consider placing MoveNext to last line.

```
while NOT prs.EOF

    RecordStatus = prs("status")    

    If (Trim(RecordStatus) = "S") Then
        response.write("Scheduled!<br>")
    Else
        response.write(RecordStatus & "<BR>")
    End If

    prs.MoveNext    
Wend
prs.Close
```

Comment: you said, "Try Trim(RecordStatus) = "S"". That worked too. Thanks for the suggestion I will try that too.

Answer (score 0):

Same result, half the code:

```
do while NOT prs.EOF
    RecordStatus = ucase(trim(prs("status")))
    If RecordStatus = "S" Then response.write "Scheduled!<br>" Else response.write RecordStatus & "<br>"
    prs.MoveNext
loop
prs.close
```

You could also do this logic check with a case statement inside the SQL query itself:

```
select case lower(status) when 's' then 'Scheduled!' else status end as sresult from <yourdatabase>
```

Then use the code:

```
do while NOT prs.EOF
    sresult = prs("sresult") & "<br>"
    response.write sresult
    prs.MoveNext
loop
prs.close
```

Hope it help :)